# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\Inventory\addavaya.php on line 20

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and get the message Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in .. on line 20. I would be ever so grateful if someone could help me with this error as it's really started to stress me out. Been on dreamweaver and it says error where it says $Username=... But I just can't seem to fix it

```
<?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="xxx"; // Mysql username 
    $password="xxx"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="xxx"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="avaya"; // Table name

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    mysql_select_db("inventory", $con)


    $addavaya="INSERT INTO avaya_pabx(critical_spare_id, serial_no, ,comcode, version, circuit_pack, classification, location, availability, date, client)
    VALUES ('$_POST[critical_spare_id]', '$_POST[serial_no]', '$_POST[comcode]', '$_POST[version]', '$_POST[circuit_pack]', 
    '$_POST[classification]', '$_POST[location]' , '$_POST[availability]', '$_POST[date]', '$_POST[client]')";


    mysql_query($addavaya,$con)

    if (!mysql_query($addavaya,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2362466

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing semi colon:

```
mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);
                                  ^
```

You should concatenate the query:

```
$addavaya="INSERT INTO avaya_pabx(critical_spare_id, serial_no, ,comcode, version, circuit_pack, classification, location, availability, date, client)
    VALUES ('". $_POST['critical_spare_id'] . "', '" . $_POST['serial_no']. "', etc...
```

Also please stop using the old `mysql_*` functions. Use either `mysqli_*` or PDO. mysql_* functions will be deprecated in the future.

And [please please **please**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) sanitize the input before querying the database!

Comment: Thanks but i still encounter this problem,
Notice: Undefined index: serial_no in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\Inventory\addavaya.php on line 21 Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comcode, version, circuit_pack, classification, location, availability, date, cl' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` is an associative array, so you need to be accessing it using single quotes, for example:

```
$_POST['critical_spare_id'] instead of $_POST[critical_spare_id]
```

This means you will have to use the concatenation operator in your query.

```
$addavaya="INSERT INTO avaya_pabx(critical_spare_id, serial_no, ,comcode, version, circuit_pack, classification, location, availability, date, client)
    VALUES ('" . $_POST['critical_spare_id'] . "', ...
```

Alternatively (and for your own good), you could use parameterized queries with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Thanks but i still encounter this problem, Notice: Undefined index: serial_no in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\Inventory\addavaya.php on line 21 Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comcode, version, circuit_pack, classification, location, availability, date, cl' at line 1

Comment: The undefined index is because you are not passing a "serial_no" variable through your `$_POST` form, so `$_POST['serial_no']` does not exist. The second is probably because of the extra comma you have in front of "comcode" in your select statement.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `;` to the end of `mysql_select_db("inventory", $con)`